# How to re-use a variable in multiple Mono operators?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Consider this code:

```
Mono.just(myVar)
    .flatMap(MyClass::heavyOperation)
    .flatMap(MyClass::anotherHeavyOperation)
    .flatMap(res -> doSomething(res, MyClass.heavyOperation(myVar)));
```

I don't want to call twice `MyClass.heavyOperation(myVar)` with the same input for the sake of performance.

How can I reuse the result of the second operation in the fourth one?

I want to do something like this, which is forbidden:

```
Object myObj;
Mono.just(myVar)
    .flatMap(var -> {
               myObj = MyClass.heavyOperation(var);                  
               return myObj;
               })
    .flatMap(MyClass::anotherHeavyOperation)
    .flatMap(res -> doSomething(res, myObj));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the best solution is to put everything that uses `myObj` in the same pipeline step.

Like this:

```
Mono.just(myVar)
    .flatMap(MyClass::heavyOperation)
    .flatMap(myObj -> MyClass.anotherHeavyOperation(myObj)
        .flatMap(res -> doSomething(res, myObj)));
```

The step that uses `myObj` can in turn be de-composed into a number of smaller sub-pipelines, and the top level pipeline can also continue as normally.

This is the basis of monadic operations in functional languages!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a tuple in the second flat map:

```
Mono.just(myVar)
    .flatMap(MyClass::heavyOperation)
    .flatMap(x -> Tuples.of(x, MyClass.anotherHeavyOperation(myVar))
    .flatMap(res -> doSomething(res.getT2(), res.getT1()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider keeping the scope:

```java
Mono.just(myVar)
    .flatMap(var -> {
        Object myObj = MyClass.heavyOperation(var);                  
        return MyClass.anotherHeavyOperation(myObj)
            .flatMap(res -> doSomething(res, myObj));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save `Mono` to variable and then just zip it again with `Mono` after `anotherHeavyOperation`.

```
var heavyOperation = Mono.just(myVar)
    .flatMap(MyClass::heavyOperation)
    .cache();

heavyOperation
   .flatMap(MyClass::anotherHeavyOperation)
   .zipWith(heavyOperation, (res, ho) -> doSomething(res, ho));
```

Comment: Although this answer is selected as the best answer, it is wrong and will do the heavy operation twice because it is [cold](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold). Please be aware of it.

Comment: @bsideup You're right, but `cache` will fix it :) Corrected my answer. Thanks for the remark.